# How do I serialise/deserialise protobuf in akka http?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, akka-http

I'm using Akka Http 2.4.7. For Json (that use json4s), serialisation is something like this:

```
entity(as[CaseClass]) { serialisedCaseClass => .... }
```

for deserialising, I just return a case class object.

I wonder is there a similar way for protobuf?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't anything available out of the box (but I agree it would be nice to have). You currently need to build your own custom unmarshaller to do that (as of akka-http 2.4.11).

You can build your own unmarshaller based on an existing protobuf definition. Here's a stub how to do it:

```
case class Person(...)

implicit val personUnmarshaller: FromEntityUnmarshaller[Person] =
  PredefinedFromEntityUnmarshallers.byteArrayUnmarshaller map { bytes =>
    // bytes is an Array[Byte]
    // call protobuf to do the unmarshalling
  }
```

and then import this definition in your route.